# Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent. React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I have a trouble with initially loading of server from my node server, there is white screen first time. But when I run second time, this is normal.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: @Chandni I have posted a solution which I found and this helped me

Comment: Make sure you launched only 1 Android Studio on your computer. In my case I had 2  AS launched the same time and as a result the debugger could not set correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you will need to:

1. Customize your tcp server for android(for iOS you don't need to customize) `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
2. Make sure, there is no any background or foreground processes in your project which is can block loading of your script into your builded application.

In my case(maybe you have another case), I had a foreground process(to track geolocation) which is blocked my main thread and blocked my start animation on initialization of application.