# game crashes after unity splash screen - cannot find stacktrace in logs

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, debugging, crash, adb

Please note: I'm not a professional developer and will probably need more detailed instructions on how to get needed information

I am working on a mobile game, currently called `EndlessTD` using Unity3d 2022.2.4f1. during testing, it used to work fine on bluestacks and in my Mi9T pro running MIUI 12.5.1 and android 11.
Developer options are active, the phone is connected to my pc via usb and displaying "USB debugging is on".

While it still works without errors in the editor on my windows machine, apparently, I screwed something up and now the game crashes right after the unity splash screen when it should load my scene.

Crash Log:

```
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   : Version '2022.2.3f1 (55531d7fa82e)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   : Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/raphael_eea/raphael:11/RKQ1.200826.002/V12.5.1.0.RFKEUXM:user/release-keys'
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   : Revision: '0'
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   : ABI: 'arm64'
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   : Timestamp: 2023-01-29 02:23:27.465468704+0100
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   : pid: 2748, tid: 2796, name: UnityMain  >>> com.EndlessRageLimited.EndlessTD <<<
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   : uid: 10467
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr --------
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   : Cause: null pointer dereference
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   :     x0  0000006ff01b7d30  x1  0000000000000000  x2  0000000000000000  x3  00000070175dcad0
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   :     x4  00000000000002ae  x5  00000070175dcad0  x6  00000000000003e9  x7  000000000000004d
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   :     x8  0000000000000000  x9  8000000000000000  x10 8000000000000000  x11 0000000000000000
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   :     x12 0000000000000001  x13 ffffffffffe00000  x14 fffffc00001fffff  x15 0000000000000000
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   :     x16 0000000000000001  x17 0000000000000000  x18 0000006fd1d7b638  x19 0000006ff01b7d30
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   :     x20 0000000000000000  x21 00000070185b1000  x22 0000006fd23111f8  x23 0000000000000000
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   :     x24 0000007015202000  x25 0000000000000000  x26 0000007015202000  x27 0000006f21abd610
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   :     x28 0000000000000001  x29 00000070151ffdd0
01-29 02:23:27.465  2748  2796 E CRASH   :     lr  0000007017a330b8  sp  00000070151ffd20  pc  0000000000000000  pst 00000000a0000000
```

My usual build settings:
[image]

Since this is my first time dealing with this, I am quite lost:

- I recently upgraded unity from 2022.2.3f1 to 2022.2.4f1 so I tried using 2022.2.3f1 again, but the error persists. Unity editor version doesnt seem to be the issue.
- Since the game is already on google play using an internal testing track, I found reports under Testing -> Pre-launch report -> Details -> stability -> Crashes and ANRs.
  Sadly, stack traces are "Fatal AndroidRuntime Exception detected." and "Native crash of com.EndlessRageLimited.EndlessTD".
  I'm not sure what to do with that information.

So more digging and it seems from the posts on the internet, people usually have a stack trace or backtrace. I dont and I dont understand why.

In the log file, there are multiple messages about not being able to load the debugger:

```
.android.camer: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521206/not-starting-debugger-since-process-cannot-load-the-jdwp-agent-react-native) on StackOverflow, it was recommended to execute `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
but this didnt change anything.

Another website recommended to enable `Wait for debugger` in developer options, but this option is greyed out for me.

Other posts on StackOverflow and other pages didnt help me to find a solution either. Did I miss anything?

What I perceive as the relevant output from `adb logcat` in command prompt is available [here](https://pastebin.com/0KLpDk59). If I interpret it correctly, it starts when the app launches.

**I now managed to get a stacktrace** using `Run device` and `Build to device`, hitting `Patch and Run` with `Development Build`, `Autoconnect Profiler`, `Deep Profiling Support` and `Script debugging` enabled.
The stack trace is available [here](https://pastebin.com/t94eJuhq)

Sadly, I cannot find any specific information on why it crashes.
After stubeling on the stacktrace utility and adding symbols for il2cpp and mono, I end up with this resolved stacktrace [here](https://pastebin.com/t94eJuhq) .

Would somebody please have some tips on what I can do to get more information on why the game crashes? Since the last test on a phone I got like 30 commits and rolling back would mean reapplying several days of work :S
Thanks!!!

Comment: I saw GameObject_CUSTOM_GetComponentInParent followed by Mesh_CUSTOM_AddBlendShapeFrame, could this be a tip? Maybe a cracked model (with blend shapes) causes the crash. Probably it is initialized from a coroutine start method.

Comment: thanks for your feedback! I couldnt find the object this code references to. It sees "git clean -fdx" kinda fixed the issue although I dont know what exactly caused it.

Answer (score 0):

after going back and forth in my git history, I decided to `git clean -fdx` to see if something on my computers side got messed up. miraculously this did indeed "fix" the issue.

While I still don't know what caused the problem, at least I dipped my feet into debugging android games using Unity and learned something new :)